# Zend Framework 2 Models Architecture

Tags: php, zend-framework2

To make my doubt clear, I have this scenario:

I have an app that sells cars and houses (just an example!), so I created a module to show all the cars, called **Cars**, and one to show all the houses, called **Houses**.

I have a **Manager** module that should have a CRUD system for Cars and Houses.

Where should I put my models for cars and houses? I should create a module just to put my models, like a `Main` module? Or I should put my models in **Cars** and **Houses** modules and access them in **Manager** module?

Let's say I create a `CarModel` with the methods *select*, *insert* and *delete*. If I put this model in `Cars` module I can have a security problem because `Cars` now have access to *insert* and *delete* methods...

On the other hand, I could create a `CarModel` inside `Cars`module with only the *select* method and then create again a `CarModel` with *insert* and *delete* in `Manager`module, but It will make very difficult to maintenance of the code...

What's the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: The only thing I can do is refer you to [this awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc/5864000#5864000)

Comment: Great, @vascowhite! This was very usefull and make things clear to me! But I'm still have a problems in how to organize the model elements fisically...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So to answer your question at a high level, there's really two ways you can go about breaking up your modules in the context you've given:

- All-in-one module (combine admin/CRUD with the actual module providing the entities and front-end stuff). One of my devs has taken this approach with this module: https://github.com/speckcommerce/SpeckCatalog
- Separate modules. For example, [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) provides no user administration, but [ZfcUserAdmin](https://github.com/Danielss89/ZfcUserAdmin) makes use of the entities / mappers in ZfcUser and provides additional user management / admin functionality.

Neither approach is wrong or right. It really just depends on your preference and how you want to break down the functionality of your application. E.g., Will you ever want to build a site that would use the Houses or Car module *without* the management / CRUD system?

On a more technical level, there's several ways you can handle "models" or "entities" using Zend\Db. Two common patterns are the [TableGateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) pattern and the [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern.

- **Table Gateway:** I've blogged about this one: http://blog.evan.pro/zf2-tablegateway-hydration
- **Data Mapper:** This is my preferred solution. I haven't blogged about this one yet, but you can find a usage example in [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/src/ZfcUser/Mapper/User.php). Also, a base data mapper is not built into ZF2 like the Table Gatway is, but it's a much more flexible solution. Check out the [AbstractDbMapper](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase/blob/master/src/ZfcBase/Mapper/AbstractDbMapper.php) provided by [ZfcBase](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase).

I'll take this opportunity to tease a couple of slides from the ZF2 tutorial that [Rob Allen](http://akrabat.com/) and I gave at PHPNW12 and will also be [giving again at ZendCon in a couple of weeks](http://zendcon.com/tutorials/#session-22966):

[Table Gateway http://evan.pro/caps/2ddbaf.png](http://evan.pro/caps/2ddbaf.png)
[Table Gateway Select http://evan.pro/caps/0904b8.png](http://evan.pro/caps/0904b8.png)
[AbstractDbMapper http://evan.pro/caps/a31480.png](http://evan.pro/caps/a31480.png)
[Mapper Select http://evan.pro/caps/a2a04f.png](http://evan.pro/caps/a2a04f.png)
[Summary http://evan.pro/caps/3ec9e6.png](http://evan.pro/caps/3ec9e6.png)

Comment: Great, Evan! Thank you very much! I guess I'll choose the All-in-one approuch and creat a admin module that route the CRUD funcionallity. I found this [ZF-Commons / ZfcAdmin](https://github.com/Zf-Commons/ZfcAdmin) and maybe it can help me. I'll install thoose modules ZfcUser and ZfcUserAdmin to study them too. Did you have a link where I can find more info about this AbstractDbMapper? tnks!